# How can I show metadata for my front page only (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, search-engine, meta

Okey so I want to add metadata for the search engines but I only want them to be added on the front page. I have been trying diferent addons but they dont seem to be working so I was thinking of just doing it with good old simple code.

I am trying this right now

```
<?php
if ( is_home() ) 
{
?>

<meta name="DC.title" content="XXXXXXXX - XXXXXXXXX.se"/>
<meta name="title" content="XXXXXXXX - XXXXXXXXX.se"/>
<meta name="keywords" content="foo, bar, orange, testing" />
<meta name="DC.format" content="text/html"/>
<meta name="DC.publisher" content="XXXXXXXX"/>

<meta name="DC.Description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sodales neque a nibh blandit at iaculis est ultrices."/>
<meta name="description" content="Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Proin sodales neque a nibh blandit at iaculis est ultrices."/>
<?php 
} 
else 
{
// This is not a homepage
}
```

but when I inspect the page with firebug the meta tags dont show on the front page or any other page. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### What did you mean by `front page` ?

Anyways, actually `is_front_page()` returns true if the user is on the page or page of posts that is set to the front page on `Settings` and `is_home()` returns true when on the posts list page, this is usually the page that shows the latest posts. So try

```
if(is_home() || is_front_page()){
    //...
}
```

instead of

```
if (is_home()) {...}
```

Hope it'll work on both cases.

Comment: Ah there it it, didn't see there was a separate for home page and front page, thanks alot.

Answer (score 0):

never mind I used is_page() instead and specified the page I wanted to use, and it works without any problems.